# Mobile SharePoint site navigate only to the top level site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, mobile, intranet, networking

We are having a problem with our mobile sharepoint site. The links to the subsite takes us back to the top level site when clicked on mobile devices such iPads, iPhones, Blackberry smart phones, and on all other smart phones.

For example:
We have a top level site named MyCompany and three subsites (HR, SALES, and Marketing). Whenever we click on the subsite the link takes us back to the home page of MyCompany.

We used firefox, safari, Opera, & IE but still getting the same issue. This doesn't happen when we access it on notebooks and PCs though.

PS: It only happens when we access the link outside of the company network.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. Cross-firewall access zone wasn't set up. I just created alternated access mapping and mapped that zone to cross-firewall access zone.

Thank you.